# Google mT5-small configuration error because number attention heads is not divider of model dimension

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, allennlp

The configuration file for the HuggingFace **google/mt5-small** Model (https://huggingface.co/google/mt5-small)

defines

```
{
...
  "d_model": 512,
...
  "num_heads": 6,
...
}
```

Link to the config file: https://huggingface.co/google/mt5-small/resolve/main/config.json

**Question:**

As far as I understood, the number of attention-head should be a divider of the model dimension. This is clearly not true in this config file.

Do I misunderstand how self-attention is applied in mT5?

When I use the AllenNLP model (https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-models/blob/main/allennlp_models/generation/models/t5.py)
as sequence-to-sequence model, I receive an error message

**Summary:**

```
allennlp.common.checks.ConfigurationError: The hidden size (512) is not a multiple of the number of attention heads (6)
```

**Full**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/pycharm-professional/269/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1500, in _exec
    runpy._run_module_as_main(module_name, alter_argv=False)
  File "/home/lars/anaconda3/envs/mare2/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/home/lars/anaconda3/envs/mare2/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/lars/anaconda3/envs/mare2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allennlp/__main__.py", line 50, in <module>
    run()
  File "/home/lars/anaconda3/envs/mare2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allennlp/__main__.py", line 46, in run
    main(prog="allennlp")
  File "/home/lars/anaconda3/envs/mare2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allennlp/commands/__init__.py", line 123, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/home/lars/anaconda3/envs/mare2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allennlp/commands/train.py", line 112, in train_model_from_args
    train_model_from_file(
  File "/home/lars/anaconda3/envs/mare2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allennlp/commands/train.py", line 178, in train_model_from_file
    return train_model(
  File "/home/lars/anaconda3/envs/mare2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allennlp/commands/train.py", line 254, in train_model
    model = _train_worker(
  File "/home/lars/anaconda3/envs/mare2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allennlp/commands/train.py", line 490, in _train_worker
    train_loop = TrainModel.from_params(
  File "/home/lars/anaconda3/envs/mare2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allennlp/common/from_params.py", line 652, in from_params
    return retyped_subclass.from_params(
  File "/home/lars/anaconda3/envs/mare2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allennlp/common/from_params.py", line 686, in from_params
    return constructor_to_call(**kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "/home/lars/anaconda3/envs/mare2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allennlp/commands/train.py", line 766, in from_partial_objects
    model_ = model.construct(
  File "/home/lars/anaconda3/envs/mare2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allennlp/common/lazy.py", line 82, in construct
    return self.constructor(**contructor_kwargs)
  File "/home/lars/anaconda3/envs/mare2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allennlp/common/lazy.py", line 66, in constructor_to_use
    return self._constructor.from_params(  # type: ignore[union-attr]
  File "/home/lars/anaconda3/envs/mare2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allennlp/common/from_params.py", line 652, in from_params
    return retyped_subclass.from_params(
  File "/home/lars/anaconda3/envs/mare2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allennlp/common/from_params.py", line 686, in from_params
    return constructor_to_call(**kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "/home/lars/anaconda3/envs/mare2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allennlp_models/generation/models/t5.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.t5 = T5Module.from_pretrained_module(
  File "/home/lars/anaconda3/envs/mare2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allennlp/modules/transformer/transformer_module.py", line 251, in from_pretrained_module
    model = cls._from_config(config, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lars/anaconda3/envs/mare2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allennlp/modules/transformer/t5.py", line 852, in _from_config
    return cls(
  File "/home/lars/anaconda3/envs/mare2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allennlp/modules/transformer/t5.py", line 783, in __init__
    self.encoder: T5EncoderStack = encoder.construct(
  File "/home/lars/anaconda3/envs/mare2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allennlp/common/lazy.py", line 82, in construct
    return self.constructor(**contructor_kwargs)
  File "/home/lars/anaconda3/envs/mare2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allennlp/modules/transformer/t5.py", line 600, in basic_encoder
    self_attention=block_self_attention.construct(
  File "/home/lars/anaconda3/envs/mare2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allennlp/common/lazy.py", line 82, in construct
    return self.constructor(**contructor_kwargs)
  File "/home/lars/anaconda3/envs/mare2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allennlp/common/lazy.py", line 66, in constructor_to_use
    return self._constructor.from_params(  # type: ignore[union-attr]
  File "/home/lars/anaconda3/envs/mare2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allennlp/common/from_params.py", line 686, in from_params
    return constructor_to_call(**kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "/home/lars/anaconda3/envs/mare2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allennlp/modules/transformer/attention_module.py", line 471, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/lars/anaconda3/envs/mare2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allennlp/modules/transformer/attention_module.py", line 91, in __init__
    raise ConfigurationError(
allennlp.common.checks.ConfigurationError: The hidden size (512) is not a multiple of the number of attention heads (6)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very good question, and shows a common misconception about Transformers, stemming from an (unfortunate) formulation in the [original Transformers paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762.pdf). In particular, the authors write the following in Section 3.2.2:

> In this work, we employ `h = 8` parallel attention layers, or heads. For each of these **we use** `d_k = d_v = d_(model) / h = 64`. [...]

Note that the equality of `d_k/d_v = d_(model)` is not strictly necessary; it is only important that you do match the final hidden representation (`d_(model)`) *after the Feed-Forward portion of each layer*. Specifically for `mt5-small`, the authors actually use an internal dimension of `384` which is simply the product of parameters `d_kv * num_heads = 64 * 6`.

Now, the problem is that many libraries make a similar assumption of the enforced relation between `d_kv` and `d_(model)`, because it saves some implementation effort that most people won't use anyways. I suspect (not super familiar with AllenNLP) that they have made similar assumptions here, which is why you cannot load the model.

Also, to clarify this, here is a peek at the `modules` of a loaded `mt5-small`:

```py
T5Block(
    (layer): ModuleList(
        (0): T5LayerSelfAttention(
        (SelfAttention): T5Attention(
            (q): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=384, bias=False)
            (k): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=384, bias=False)
            (v): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=384, bias=False)
            (o): Linear(in_features=384, out_features=512, bias=False)
        )
        (layer_norm): T5LayerNorm()
        (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
        (1): T5LayerFF(
        (DenseReluDense): T5DenseGatedGeluDense(
            (wi_0): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=1024, bias=False)
            (wi_1): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=1024, bias=False)
            (wo): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=512, bias=False)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
        (layer_norm): T5LayerNorm()
        (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
    )
)
```

You can get the full model layout by simply calling `list(model.modules())`

Comment: Great explanation, absolutely solved my misunderstanding.